# Contacts and ContactsContract in the same app

Tags: android

I have it done right now with an if statement and the code for each every time, but what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class AddContacts{
    public static void newContacts(){

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, Directory.ResultsDetails[0]);
        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, Directory.ResultsDetails[4]);
        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, 3);
        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, Directory.ResultsDetails[3]);
        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, 2);

        startActivity(i);
    }

    public static void oldContacts(){

        Intent i = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.Insert.ACTION, Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI);
        i.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME, Directory.ResultsDetails[0]);
        i.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.PHONE, Directory.ResultsDetails[4]);
        i.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, 3);
        i.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, Directory.ResultsDetails[3]);
        i.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, 2);

        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

and then have something like:

```
if(sdk >=5){
    AddContacts.newContacts();
}else{
    AddContacts.oldContacts();}
```

when the 'Add to Contacts' button is pressed.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how I should do this. I tried making a new class in the package (AddContacts) and putting those in, but it won't let me start an activity that way. I'd like to push this code out to it's own class because it will save some clutter in the rest of my app. Any help is appreciated!

The error I get is on startActivity(i); | The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type AddContacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type AddContacts

Have `newContacts()` and `oldContacts()` take an `Activity` as a parameter, and call `startActivity()` on that `Activity`.

However, your code here will not work in general. If you are trying to support Android 1.x, you cannot refer to `ContactsContract` in a class that will be loaded into the VM, since `ContactsContract` won't exist -- you will get a `VerifyError` at runtime. Conversely, if you are only trying to support Android 2.x/3.x, then skip `Contacts` outright and only worry about `ContactsContract`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners) demonstrating accessing both `Contacts` and `ContactsContract`, in a backwards-compatible way, where it will use `Contacts` on 1.x and `ContactsContract` on 2.x/3.x. In this case I am querying the providers, but the same concept holds for inserting as well.

That being said, I would recommend just supporting Android 2.x/3.x for a brand new app, as 1.x is around 4% of the market at the moment, and falling.

Comment: I should add two new classes (AddContactOld and AddContactNew) and have each one do their respective tasks? That makes sense, I don't know why I didn't realize that.

Comment: @Rob: The key of the sample is that only one of those is loaded into the VM, depending on `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`. On a newer Android, you technically could load either, but we only worry about the new interface. On an older Android, though, we avoid loading the class that refers to `ContactsContract`, and therefore avoid the `VerifyError`. This is a bit clunky compared to two methods and an `if()` statement, but it's what you need in this case.

Comment: I got it working. After passing the methods an activity, I would've understood that "Hey, this is crashing because it has no idea what this new stuff is at all."

I want to impress that this works with both old and new devices, so having it all in there is important in this case. Thanks!